# Explicit description for $G=\langle a,b,c\mid[a,b]=b\,,\,[b,c]=c\,,\,[c,a]=a\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I am trying to give an explicit description of the group $$G=\langle a,b,c\mid[a,b]=b\,,\,[b,c]=c\,,\,[c,a]=a\rangle\,.$$
Generalizing to fewer generators, one ends up with the trivial group, i.e.
$$G_0=\langle\,\rangle\cong G_1=\langle a\mid [a,a]=a\rangle\cong G_2=\langle a,b\mid[a,b]=b\,,\,[b,a]=a\rangle\cong 1\,.$$
But I don't see a reason, why this should hold for $G=G_3$ or $G_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Edit**: I am sorry, I thought the symbols were standard. $[a,b]$ is defined as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. This makes it a little less trivial.

Comment: Your edit does not change the argument given in the answer.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: It does! $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=b$ does not imply $a=b=1$. We will need to use all three relations.

Comment: Ahh, right. I got the signs mixed up in my head.

Comment: Asking for an "explicit description" is a rather vague question. Can you be more explicit about what kind of explicitness you want?

Comment: One thing I can say is that many options of "explicit descriptions" are immediately ruled out because I'm pretty sure that this group fails to fall into several classes of groups for which standard "explicit descriptions" are available: this group is not word hyperbolic, it is not automatic, ...

Comment: @LeeMosher: If $G$ was indeed trivial, a verification of this would of course suffice. Else, I would be interested in a simpler presentation or maybe a construction based on simpler groups, e.g. as a (semi)direct product, or something.

Comment: In fact the group is trivial, so it is automatic, word hyperbolic, etc. The $4$-generator version, known as the Higman group, is infinite, and is much more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of the commutator $[g,h]=g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ then this presentation is the trivial group.

**EDIT / REMARK** If the commutator is defined as $[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ (and this is what is meant following all comments), then surprisingly, the group $G$ is still trivial. This is Exercise 1 in Jean-Pierre Serre's famous book *[Trees](http://bit.ly/1lJOnbT)*, pag. 10, in the chapter that deals with Amalgams.

Comment: Here, $[g,h]$ is defined as $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok that makes a big difference!

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Do you know a proof of this result, or a place where I can find one?

Comment: @JakobWerner: http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?rd2&topic=154534&start=40#p1138025

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^{-1} b^{-1} ab = b$, by left multiplying both sides by $a$, we get $b^{-1} ab = ab$, whence $b^{-1}=1$. Thus, $b=1$.  Similarly, we get that $a$ and $c$ also equal the identity.